# Trying to make large background image remain centered with an auto margin centered content div, but bg image should not affect layout

Tags: html, css

i want a background image that is larger than the content, which will remain centered with the content, but will not affect the layout (meaning no scrollbars to accomodate the background image). the content *must* be centered using margin: auto; so that the left side will remain flush with the left side of the viewpane, when the viewpane becomes smaller than the content.

I have seen this question asked several times, and have tried quite a few solutions, but none of the accepted answers have actually worked.

**Edit to Clarify**

This question is still a bit murkey, so I will attempt to clarify with some images showing what I need. In these images, green is the background image, red is the main content, and blue is the browser's viewpane.

[image]

**A:** When the viewpane is smaller than both the background image and the main content, the left side of the content remains flush with the left side of the viewpane, the background image remains centered to the main content, the viewpanes scrollbars will only scroll out to the right edge of the main content (and not to the right edge of the background).

**B:** When the viewpane is larger than both the background image and content, both remain centered to the viewpane.

**C:** When the viewpane is the same size as the main content, the background image should remain centered to the main content, no scrollbars should be present.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're talking about.

Comment: @animuson i don't know how to explain it any simpler. I want the out div to affect the layout. i want the inner div to not affect the layout, but the overflow should still be visible.

Comment: Something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/v6ZHx/)?

Comment: unfortunately i need the inner div to remain 100% visible, yet only the outer div should affect the layout.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Updated Answer**: I still have spent way too much time on this :-), especially when it ended up so simple. *It allows for a background to be sized based on the height of the container*, which seems to be different than yunzen's solution. **Now does use `margin: 0 auto;`**. Still grows with container height.

[**View the new answer.**](http://jsfiddle.net/CNxCb/219/)

You can [**view the original, more complex answer**](http://jsfiddle.net/CNxCb/214/) which does not use `auto` margin.

### HTML:

```
<div id="Bkg">
   <div id="Content">Content goes here. </div>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
#Bkg {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 300px; /* equals width of content */
    background:url('http://dummyimage.com/400x20/ffff00/000000&text=Center') repeat-y top center;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

#Content {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
```

Comment: interesting take. I will have to compare the two tonight and see what fits best.

Comment: Sorry Scott, while both of your answers work. yanzun's was first. Thank you very much for your time though. I appreciate this help a lot.

Comment: @dqhendricks--No problem. If the content height issue is not a problem for you then great. I would appreciate an upvote though :-), I probably spent 3+ hours on this to try and find a solution that changed with content height (I actually thought that was what you wanted based on your pictures).

Comment: Sure thing. Had an example page that had the closest I came, which would have shown that the bg height was fixed, but other posters got confused by the example page so I took it down. again, thank you for you help. the above answer looks very simple. I will test tonight and perhaps switch accepted answer.

Comment: This seems to be much better than my answer. If I could, I would award the bounty back to you. Maybe I can.

Comment: I started a bounty, which I want to give to ScottS

Comment: @yunzen--I'm quite taken aback. Thank you for your generosity and thoughtfulness.

Comment: @ScottS I think you deserve it

Answer (score 3):

I guess [this](http://jsfiddle.net/HerrSerker/K77pL/) is what you want

---

### HTML

```
<div id="content">
    content<br/><br /><br/>
    content<br/>
</div>
<div id="background"><div></div></div>
```

---

### CSS

```
html, body {
   height: 100%;
}

#background {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    /* this is the height of the bg image */
    min-height: 600px;
    z-index: -1;
}
#background > div {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: url("http://lorempixel.com/800/600/sports/2") no-repeat 50% top gray;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    /* this is the height of the content */
    min-width: 500px;
    /* this is the width of the bg image */
    max-width: 800px;
    /* this is the height of the bg image */
    max-height: 600px;
    z-index: -1;
}
#content {
    /* these are just some numbers */
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid gold;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}
```

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I am looking for. I will test this out tonight and accept if it works as I believe it will.

Comment: @dqhendricks and yunzen--it appears this would work well if you have a fixed height to your content, but more content would seem to cause issues http://jsfiddle.net/K77pL/11/. I think I have a solution that allows for flexible height content.

Comment: @ScottS I can't see any real difference. You just deleted the height of the content and put more content into it. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Correct, the background image does not carry down the page with the content. Apparently that was not a concern to @dqhendricks, but that is the difference between them. I actually just updated my answer to a laughably simple solution, which when I looked back, was basically sandeep's answer only with a `min-width` added to the outer background div.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if it expands past the browser's window size, it's going to create a scrollbar for the entire window. I wasn't sure exactly what scrollbar you're trying to prevent.

`max-width` tells it "under no circumstances should this box be bigger than this width." So a box bigger than that will simply expand past the parent's boundaries.

[See the jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/v6ZHx/)

Comment: sorry realized that this actually did not work. the inner div's content gets cut off at the border of the outer div. i need the entire inner div to remain visible.

Comment: added an image to the original post to attempt to clarify

Comment: If we choose max-width: 100%; we are able to do it. Look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the question right, I believe this is what you're wanting.

```
.main-container
{
    height: 1005px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -560px;
    position: relative;
    width: 1120px;
}
```

To hide the scrollbars, you can add

```
overflow: hidden;
```

For horizontal only:

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```

Comment: that would hide the content wouldn't it? I don't want to hide it, I just want it to not affect the layout.

Comment: i want the scrollbars to appear when the outer div goes beyond the viewpane, but not when the inner div goes beyond the viewpane.

Comment: Then you would set the overflow on the inner div. Although I'm not 100% sure I'm actually answering what you're asking.

Comment: there is nothing contained in the inner div. it only has a background image. setting overflow on that would affect nothing.

Comment: this does not answer the question. this centers a div, and not in the way that I want. The div should be centered using margin: auto; so that the left side remains flush with the left side of the viewpane if the viewpane becomes narrower than the content.

Comment: added an image to the original post to attempt to clarify.

Comment: I'm mostly confused about the link you provided. Your content is one giant image. Is that the background or the "main content"

Comment: again, i don't want to hide any scrollbars.

Comment: there are two divs in the example, the outer div is the main content, the inner div is the background image. don't get too hung up on the example. it is merely the closest i could get to a solution. i simply want a background image that is larger than the content, which will remain centered with the content, but will not affect the layout (meaning no scrollbars to accomodate the background image). the content MUST be centered using margin: auto; so that the left side will remain flush with the left side of the viewpane when the viewpane becomes smaller than the content.

Comment: Why is the outer div not the background and the content in the inner div?

Comment: because i can't make the background image go out the left side (negative margin), and center correctly (auto margin), at the same time... i did it the above way because that was as close to what i want as I could get...

Comment: How about setting the background of the body?
background: url("BG IMAGE URL") center;

Comment: no, because when the content is smaller than the viewpane, the background image continues to stay centered with the viewpane, while the content's left side never goes past the left side of the viewpane, causing the content and the background image to become misaligned.................................

Answer (score 0):

Try this then:

```
<div id="wrapper" style="position:relative;margin:auto;width:200px;height:200px;">
<div id="image" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:-100px;width:400px;height:400px;background-image:url(your_bgimage);background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:top center;">
<div id="content" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:100px;width:200px;height:200px;"><p>
<p>/* YOUR CONTENT */</P>
</div></div></div>
```

For some reason I couldn't get the z-index work, but if you can, you can put your content in the `wrapper` too, and `content` is not needed.

Comment: this fails under scenario A and C.

Comment: Quite opposite, it does not work in scenario B. In fact A and C are same. Try this on blank page without any other styles, you'll see what I mean.

Comment: you are right in that it also fails under scenario B, but it also fails under A and C. The left side of the inner content should remain flush with the left side of the viewpane, but in your example, the left side of the background image remains flush with the left side of the viewpane instead. in fact your content and background image are the same size, which is not what I asked for at all. the left side of the background image should go past the left side of the viewpane when the viewpane is smaller than the background image.

Comment: Added `margin:auto;`. Looks to me that it works exactly you want. Or then I jus have not understood the question.

Comment: Yes, you have misunderstood. The content is a different size than the background image. the content is what should be centered with margin auto, not the background image. otherwise when the viewpane is smaller than the background image, the left side of teh background image will be flush with the left side of the viewpane instead of the left side of the content beiung flush with the left side of the viewpane....................

Comment: check out @yunzen's jsfiddle link to see what I want.

Comment: with absolute positioning, the content/background image will not stay centered in scenario B.

Comment: On my screen it does. How ever it fails when resizing from B towards A, scrollbars will be shown immediately when the viewpane gets smaller than image. I think yunzen has the best solution at the time.

Answer (score 0):

Given your original diagram I assumed that the background image was intended to be that - an image, possibly hi-res, rather than a repeated pattern. You may want to play with css3 [background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-size) property which is handy for this specific purpose. It is well supported by modern browsers and regresses reasonably well if you have to support IE8 and under.

```
body {
  background-image:url(/*nice higher res picture*/);
  background-size:cover;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YyzAX/